# Never returning from call to boost singleton

Tags: serialization, boost, singleton

I have a class, which is a boost serialization singleton. I need to do some initialization inside the main function of the program. So I made a public function in the singleton class, which I call in the main function. 
Unfortunately the function somehow seems to never return, causing the remainder of the main function to not be executed... If I put a cout statement at the end of the called function, it does get printed, so nothing in the function itself is blocking.

I also found out that the singleton constructor is called before the main function is called.

I feel I'm missing something here. 
Can somebody shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you posting riddles? Firstly. Singletons are almost always a bad idea. Secondly: you show no code. We have to make stuff up. Sadly, we can't make up the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb8fdd92adec083c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that boost::communicator must be called inside the main function:

```
boost::environment env(argc, argv);
```

There is a env definition which doesn't take arguments, but this didn't work in my case(don't know why).